# SATA3 and Hotswap mainboard?

Tags: sata, hotswapping

Currently I am on a budget and I want to buy a cheap Intel Pentium mainboard but I need Sata3 and Hotswap. I eyeballed the MSI H81M-P33 is this any good for hotswap?

Comment: I can't find any concrete data, but I've not had any issues with hotswapping SATA as long as the SATA ports are configured in AHCI mode (not IDE emulation) on Intel chipsets.

Comment: Can you write an answer? It seems right but the only issue is I can't remove the device with windows device manager.